# Find index in PCM WAV file after silence with Python

Tags: python, audio, indexing, wav

I need to be able to find the index, preferably in milliseconds, of a WAV segment immediately after a pause (silence). I'll use this index to indicate where speech starts for a new sentence after the pause of the previous sentence. I can provide a segment of two or three seconds that will contain the pause and speech on both sides.

I have looked at Python Wave on how to open and save the file, but I'm not sure how to find the first sound after the relative silence and get the index.

#### Update:

My purpose is to index Bible verses so a user can select any verse and hear it read. Once the index for the first hint of sound is found, I'll back it up a few dozen milliseconds for a lead in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my application once, but I copied/pasted it from SO. Thanks to the person who wrote it ;)

```
import wave

handle = wave.open('file', 'r')

for i in range(handle.getnframes()):
  frame = handle.readframes(i)

  zero = True

  for j in range(len(frame)):
    if ord(frame[j]) > 0:
      zero = False
      break

    if zero:
      print 'Silence found at frame {0}'.format(handle.tell())
```

Comment: This won't work well for actual audio. Using an actual microphone you're never going to get true 0 readings in a meaningful way. A much better way would be to keep a moving average over some number of samples (half a second?) and if the average absolute magnitude drops below a threshold, treat that as silence.

Comment: I was thinking of just recording a few seconds of silence and just averaging that, and then using that value as the threshold. I used this to split up a music CD which had pure silence in between tracks, so I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Maybe. Depends on this source of the audio too. Something off, say, a handheld digital recorder or cellphone is going to be a lot worse than something recoreded on a decent mic in a closed room.

Comment: This is a professionally recorded audio made in a studio. The silence appears as a flat line in an editor but there, of course, is still an occasional "pop" or anomaly so the running average method would likely be best.

What is the best way to use the Python wave module to analyze a range of frames?